# How can I use avahi without a network connection?

Tags: networking, avahi

How can I test software that uses avahi while my laptop is disconnected from any router?

All of the services run on the same machine, so Avahi would be advertising an IP address of 127.0.0.1 for all of the services.

As an example, I am using a file at `/etc/avahi/services/postgresql.service` to register a database:

```
$ cat /etc/avahi/services/postgresql.service
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
  <name>my_database_name</name>
  <service>
    <type>_postgresql._tcp</type>
    <port>5432</port>
  </service>
</service-group>
```

When I am connected to the router, `avahi-browse` shows the service:

```
$ avahi-browse -a | grep my_database_name
+  wlan0 IPv6 my_database_name                              PostgreSQL Server    local
+  wlan0 IPv4 my_database_name                              PostgreSQL Server    local
```

When I am disconnected from the router, `avahi-browse` no longer shows any services and my software cannot find the database:

```
$ avahi-browse -a
```

Here is my interface information when I am disconnected:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:ac:a6:37  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f3900000-f3920000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3637633 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3637633 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1242209987 (1.2 GB)  TX bytes:1242209987 (1.2 GB)
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 but may need to do this on other distributions as well.

**Update**: One of my (busy) friends sent me the following, which I have not been able to figure out yet:

> Avahi, by nature will not properly bind to a loop interface. You can
>   either turn up a dummy interface (best solution) or turn up a
>   non-routable number on a physical interface. (works, but can be
>   problematic if you are using a transient connection.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avahi requires that the interface have the `MULTICAST` flag set. That is,

```
ifconfig dummy0 multicast
```

Once the `MULTICAST` flag is set, avahi will automatically advertise services on that interface, no need to restart or otherwise mess with avahi configuration unless the interface is disallowed in the avahi configuration.

Comment: Complete instructions for my Ubuntu 14.04 system: enable dummy0 with: `sudo modprobe dummy` and configure it for ipv4 with: `sudo ifconfig dummy0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 multicast`

Comment: Or for ipv6 (default on my system): `sudo ifconfig dummy0 up multicast`

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging and this ticket in the Chromim project's issue tracker sounds like what you're after. The ticket: [Issue 288385: P2P: Write a fake avahi/zeroconf network to simulate a private network of peers](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=288385) has the following description:

> #### Project Member Reported by de...@chromium.org, Sep 9, 2013
>
> We want to run P2P tests on a single machine, faking the rest of the
>   peers. This requires to isolate the avahi/zeroconf traffic to prevent
>   seeing services from other DUTs on the same network and also expose
>   services to the network.
>
> The libavahi, used by p2p and update_engine, uses a private API to
>   contact the avahi-daemon over DBus, thus replacing the avahi-daemon
>   with a fake implementation would require to implement this interface
>   that's not documented. Replacing the libavahi requires to compile a
>   different version or use a fake libavahi interface that kind of looses
>   the point of having an integration autotest test.
>
> To fake the network of peers, another option is to create a TAP
>   interface with a python script that fakes all the required avahi
>   traffic, and let avahi-daemon listen ONLY on that interface during the
>   test (we can do this through the avahi-daemon config file).

I looked through this ticket and it seems to have all the pieces you'd need, but figuring out how to put them together is missing. Perhaps you could drop a line to the Chromium project asking for some assistance with these pieces might be a good place to start.

#### References

- [LANSim](http://lansim.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Is this still what you would recommend even though I am not interested in faking other machines, but just one (the localhost) machine?

Comment: @Oleg - I'm still searching for other methods and coming up empty. This is one approach that I've found, it seems like overkill for what you want though, but it does appear to be at least 1 option.

Comment: Please see the quote I added at the bottom of my question. Does that help?